# PHP. How to merge radio button and image in a way that i am going to select images in replace with the radio button icon

Tags: php, jquery

```
<fieldset id="<?php $test_name; ?>" data-set="0">
<h2 class="fs-title"><?php echo "$test_name"; ?></h2>
<input name="<?php echo "$test_name"; ?>" type="radio" value="N" >
<img src="images/<?php echo "$images_neg"; ?>"  class="case" data-case="1"/><br/>
<input name="<?php echo "$test_name"; ?>" type="radio" value="P" >
<img src="images/<?php echo "$images_pos"; ?>"  class="case" data-case="2"/><br/>
<input name="<?php echo "$test_name"; ?>" type="radio" value="I" >
<img src="images/<?php echo "$images_inv"; ?>"  class="case" data-case="3"/><br/>
<input name="<?php echo "$test_name"; ?>" type="radio" value="S" >
<img src="images/skip_button.fw.png"  class="case" data-case="4"/><br/>
<br/>

<?php if ($num_test > 1) { ?>
<input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
<?php }?>

<br/>

<?php if($num_test == 1) { ?>

<input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
<input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="action-button" value="SAVE" />
<?php }?>

</fieldset>
```

What should i do to merge radio button and image in a way that i am going to select images in replace with the radio button icon? All this codes are inside a loop and the loop is perfectly fine! The images and radio button can be seen but it is separated (Cannot select image in replace of the radio button). SOLVE!
OTHER PROBLEM!
 However, when i select it, there is red box surround the image and if i select the other one, the red box didnt change position, instead both images are surrounded in red boxes. Any way to solve this:? –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<label>
    <input name="<?=$test_name?>" type="radio" value="N" >
    <img src="images/<?=$images_neg?>"  class="case" data-case="1">
</label>
```

or you want seperate the image and radio box

```
<input name="<?=$test_name?>" type="radio" value="N" id="radio-id" >
<label for="radio-id"><img src="images/<?=$images_neg?>"  class="case" data-case="1"></label>
```

Comment: Hi, It does work out but when i select it, there is red box surround the image and if i select the other one, the red box didnt change position, instead both images are surrounded in red boxes. Any way to solve this:? –